# JTable Repeat Result

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

My problem is that I have a JTable that always prints the first line repeatedly, and ignores the following data. I think that is the problem code.

I do a query and converts it to a list to populate my JTable. I ask you to analyze my code to see if it is right.

```
 try{
        EntityManager em = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query query_resultados = em.createQuery("FROM "
        + "Resultados WHERE res_codigo LIKE "+aux);

        List<Resultados> lista_resultados = 
                (List<Resultados>) query_resultados.getResultList();

        for(int i=0; i<lista_resultados.size(); i++){

            Resultados resultado = lista_resultados.get(i);

            System.out.println("Teste: "+lista_resultados.get(i).getRes_anti_hbc_hbs());
            System.out.println("i= "+i);

            model.addRow(new Object[] {resultado.getRes_anti_hbc_hbs(), 
                resultado.getRes_anticorpos_irregulares(),
            resultado.getRes_chagas(), resultado.getRes_codigo(), 
            resultado.getRes_data(), resultado.getRes_ggpd(), 
            resultado.getRes_hbs_aq(), resultado.getRes_hcv(),
            resultado.getRes_hiv(), resultado.getRes_htlv_i_ii(), 
            resultado.getRes_malaria(), resultado.getRes_responsavel(), 
            resultado.getRes_sifilis(), resultado.getRes_t_mancha(),
            resultado.getRes_tpg()});
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro: "+e);
    }
```

Comment: I'd be looking into what `query_resultados.getResultList` is returning, checking to see that on each loop `Resultados resultado` is actually returning what you think it should be.  If that fails there is a problem with the underlying table model and or render, which you've not provided

Comment: If you find that the problem is not with the queried results, post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), using **hard coded values** (i.e. no db access code), that demonstrates the problem, so we can test it out.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it is common to iterate over a Java ResultSet by using something like this:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
    String firstColVal = rs.getString(1);
}
```

`rs.next()` ensures in this context that the next lines is fetched until all lines are done.